# Sending Email based on PS Query using Alerts and Notifications HCM92

Tags: sql, email, notifications, alert, peoplesoft

I need to come up with a PeopleSoft query that will list employees that have the same MAIL address and HOME address, then either send that list to payroll via email, or send an individual email to each employee letting them know their HOME and MAIL addresses are the same.

I figured out how to send out emails through the alerts system but all it's sending is an `stdout` file in the email body. I would like the email body to either show the list of employees with duplicate addresses or send an individualized email to each employee showing their duplicate addresses.

This is the query PS generated for me:

```
    SELECT A.EMPLID, A.ADDRESS_TYPE, A.ADDRESS1 
    FROM PS_ADDRESSES A 
    WHERE ( ( A.ADDRESS_TYPE = 'HOME' 
    OR A.ADDRESS_TYPE = 'MAIL')) 
    ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the Schedule Query functionality to send an email with the report output in attachment?

Main Menu > Reporting Tools > Query > Schedule Query

In the Process Scheduler Request pop-up set Type to Email and Format to xls, like below:
[image]

Then click on 'Distribution' and set the values for your email and the addresses, can be users, roles or just an email address you want:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm trying out that functionality now. I will let you know if I have any issues.

Comment: Not sure if you can help me with my next question, but I'm having trouble with the Query. I want the query to populate to the table ONLY if a particular persons home and mail address are the same.

Comment: you could try to join PS_ADDRESSES on itself, something like this:

`select A.EMPLID, A.ADDRESS_TYPE, A.ADDRESS1, B.ADDRESS_TYPE, B.ADDRESS1 from PS_ADDRESSES A, PS_ADDRESSES B where A.EMPLID=B.EMPLID and A.ADDRESS1=B.ADDRESS1 and A.ADDRESS_TYPE='HOME' and B.ADDRESS_TYPE='MAIL' and A.ADDRESS1<>' ' ;`

Comment: Yes, that works great. Ran it in toad and it does what I need. I can't figure out how to put that into PS query though. It's doing some automatic joins that I can't undo, as well as grouping the where clauses which is messing up the output.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it all out! Thank you for the help Robin I appreciate it.